# Send a message to an AWS Pinpoint segment from a lambda function ( node.js / javascript )

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-pinpoint

If I have a segment of users in [AWS Pinpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/) and I want to send that [segment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/segments.html) a SNS Push message from a [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) function, what API function do I use?

The [AWS Javascript SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Pinpoint.html) allows me to create and update a segment but it does **NOT** have anything that allows me to send a message to a segment.

It does have [sendMessages](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Pinpoint.html#sendMessages-property) and [sendUsersMessages](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Pinpoint.html#sendUsersMessages-property) but these do **NOT** allow me to send by segment

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segments can be delivered to via campaigns, so you would probably want to create an Immediate Campaign to deliver to your segment (can be done from within a lambda function like any AWS API).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Pinpoint.html#createCampaign-property

Edit: That API looks pretty complex, a simple example can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/campaigns.html

Comment: That tells me how to create a campaign with the API which I know how to do. But how do I SEND messages to that campaign with the API?

Comment: A campaign is simply a message sent to a segment (with advanced scheduling/sending options like local time etc...).  The messageConfiguration property of a campaign is the Message that will be sent to the SegmentId property of the campaign.